# Advanced Lava Simulation

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm to figure out how to create realistic lava.  I've watched pretty much every Blender tutorial out there on it, and they all seem to present results similar to this:

[image]

Which looks cool, but it only takes a quick look at some real lava footage to see that this isn't how lava behaves.  Observe the crust in these clips:

[image]
[image][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPvGK.png)
[image]

It moves around, breaks apart, etc, but nothing like what the above attempt makes it do.

Additionally, lava doesn't lose its shape easily.  For example, if one glob of lava lands on another glob of lava, unless both are white hot, you're going to still be able to make out those two globs for a while, and the crease between them will pretty much never go away; you can kind of see this in action here:

[image]

Another example is lava crumpling up like in this clip:

[image]

This preservation of shape is something I continue to see absent in all fluid sim demos; it seems like all demos showing "viscous" fluid still have pieces absorbing into each other pretty quickly, like in these videos below:

[Flip Fluids Viscosity Comparison - Blender](https://youtu.be/vt2wjrm7pIs)

[High Viscosity Flip Fluid - #Blender](https://youtu.be/XfgiIAKLhlo)

[Blender FLIP Fluids Addon](https://youtu.be/8hpqwfZah08)

[Blender - Fluid Simulation](https://youtu.be/3Q11S4y-Mdk)

Is it possible to make lava with these elements in Blender?  Could the Molecular Script addon do it?  I've seen some pretty amazing stuff done with that addon, but I haven't been able to really figure out how to do much with it myself.

Comment: Actually, Can Blender Stack Exchange do gifs?  These don't seem to be playing.

Comment: I don't know how well Blender would be able to do it in the base flip fluids simulator. The diffusion settings only go so far. Also, I found a post on blender artists that might help you. https://blenderartists.org/t/lava-flow-help/488305